# Azure App Service Static URL Case Changes

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Visual Studio Community to deploy a .Net 4.7.2 project to an Azure App Service instance.  Among the many things this App does is serve some static JS and CSS for embedding into client web pages.  However, each time I publish the App, the URL for the static JS and CSS is changing.
`embed/js` => `Embed/js` => `Embed/Js` => `Embed/JS` => `embed/Js` => `embed/JS` => `EMBED/js` and so on.
I've pored over the web.config file and the various settings in the Azure console with no luck.  Any suggestions, guesses, help?  Please?

Comment: Is this blocking your functionality? Where do you see this? Pls share screenshots and configurations to help you further.

Comment: This blocks me because the page that relies on the scripts never knows where to get the latest version:
```<script src="https://mypublicsite.com/embed/js/embed-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>```
vs
```<script src="https://mypublicsite.com/Embed/js/embed-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>```
returns 2 different scripts.
Which type of configurations would help (web.config, etc)?  I'm new to .NET and Visual Studio (and not liking either one at all).

Comment: I've created a simple web mvc asp.net core app, and I added a js file name myTest.js under the floder Scripts, after deploying it to azure web app, I found that it's case insensitive, I visit xxx/Scripts/myTest.js and xxx/scripts/mytest.js are both ok.

Comment: Are the folder and file name changed by yourself before unloading? Or you don't know what leads the changes of the folder and file name and you are trying to find a way to keep the folder/file name not change after deploying?

Comment: I deployed to azure web app which is in windows OS. The Windows and macOS file systems are case-insensitive (but case-preserving) by default. Most Linux filesystems are case-sensitive.

Comment: @FriendlyNeighborhoodBonehead  Good day sir, have you got  any progress? Pls feel free to share your further question if exists :).

Comment: @Tiny-wa ... the issue was when I made a change to my script then re-published.  I would be able to find A version of the code, when I needed the latest version of the code.  I didn't change the case of my folders between publish attempts as I knew that would cause this to happen.  What I think I found is that Azure was trying to protect me from myself and creating a "version" by making adjustments to the casing of the script and its path as I did each release.  After rage quitting for the weekend , now all of the different permutations of the URL return the same script

Comment: @FriendlyNeighborhoodBonehead Yeah, that sounds like an accidental phenomenon. And it seems that you can now get the correct script. Could you tell me if you used windows as the OS in azure app service?

Answer (score 0):

Sum up here. The changing folder name/file name just like a protect way to create a "version" by making adjustments to the casing of the script and its path. And it's more likely to be an accident.

And upon the changing folder name/file name, if the project is running on windows OS, it's case insensitive, but if it's running on Linux OS, it's case-sensitive.